# CountVectorizer and Out-Of-Vocabulary (OOV) tokens?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Right now I'm using `CountVectorizer` to extract features.  However, I need to count words not seen during fitting.

During transforming, the default behavior of `CountVectorizer` is to ignore words that were not observed during fitting.  But I need to keep a count of how many times this happens!

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

There is no inbuilt way in scikit-learn to do this, you need to write some additional code to be able to do this. However you could use the `vocabulary_` attribute of `CountVectorizer` to achieve this.

1. Cache the current vocabulary
2. Call fit_transform
3. Compute the diff with the new vocabulary and the cached vocabulary